# How can I force an instance created with Activator to use the method from the base class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have a class that is derived from the observable Collection class:

```
class MyClassItem
{
    ...
}

class CustomCollection : ObservableCollection<MyClassItem>
{
    public CustomCollection(){}
    public new void Add(MyClassItem item)
    {
       //...Some custom stuff that I do
       base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I have another class which is supposed to be a generic checklist implementation that can support any type and allow the caller to get a collection of their desired type. My implementation looks like this:

```
class GenericCheckListItem<T>
{
   //...My implementation stuff
   public T Item {get; set;}
}

class MyGenericCheckList<T> : ObservableCollection<GenericCheckListItem<T>>
{
    //...Some implementation stuff
    
    public CT GetSelectedItemsAsCollection<CT>() where CT: ICollection<T>
    {
        CT collection = Activator.CreateInstance<CT>();
        foreach(var item in this)
        {
            collection.Add(item.Item)
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

The above is to be used like so:

```
MyGenericCheckList<MyClassItem> cList = new MyGenericCheckList<MyClassItem>();
// ...add some stuff and edit the selection of cList
var myColl = cList.GetSelectedItemsAsCollection<CustomCollection>();
```

My issue is that I keep noticing that although the `collection` instance that is created in the `GetSelectedItemsAsCollection` method is of type CT, the `Add` method that gets called is not my shadowed implementation in `CustomCollection`, but some other (I assume the base implementation). I can tell because there is some important bookkeeping done whenever an item is added that is not being executed.

Now my question is how do I force my method to call the shadowed implementation of the Add method? If this is not possible is there some other approach I can use to achieve my desired results?

Comment: You need to use `override` instead of `new`, e.g `public override void Add(MyClassItem item)`.

Comment: I can't its not allowed for that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct/oversimplified answer to your question is to make your `CustomCollection` class implement `ICollection<MyClassItem>`:

```
class CustomCollection : ObservableCollection<MyClassItem>, ICollection<MyClassItem>
```

This makes your collection, *when cast as an `ICollection<MyClassItem>`*, recognize your new `Add` method as the one which implements that interface. However, it will not have the same behavior if you cast an item as `ObservableCollection<MyClassItem>`.

The longer, probably more correct answer is that it's generally a bad idea to extend basic collection types like this. Most likely whatever you're trying to accomplish with this can probably be accomplished in other ways. For example, you should be able to do your "important book keeping" by subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` handler on a plain old `ObservableCollection`. If you're adding other features to your custom collection class, consider using a container class instead, with the `ObservableCollection` as a separate *property* on that class. In other words, using *composition* instead of *inheritance*.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but the use case of CustomColleciton is to be bound as the ItemSource for a ListView, so I do need it to implement ObservableCollection.

Comment: My goal is to have it so that GetSelectedItemAsCollection can return a collection of any type and use its Add method. Do you know of a cleaner way to approach this?

Comment: @Kikanye: The requirement isn't as clear to me as it probably seems to you. In theory, you could use reflection to find and call the `Add` method. It would probably even work to cast the collection as `dynamic` (i.e. `((dynamic)collection).Add(item.Item)`). But it feels like you're trying to work against the whole C# type system, and I wouldn't feel comfortable suggesting that approach without having a better understanding of your requirements and exploring other options.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code works as you expect it. I've tried it like this

```cs
public class Person
{
   public string FirstNames { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonsCollection : ObservableCollection<Person>
{
   public new void Add(Person person)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"PersonsCollection.Add: {person.FirstNames} {person.LastName}");
      Console.WriteLine($"no of items before add: {this.Count}");
      base.Add(person);
      Console.WriteLine($"no of items after add: {this.Count}");
   }
}

public class CollectionFactory<T>
{
   public CT CreateCollection<CT>() where CT: ICollection<T>
      => Activator.CreateInstance<CT>();
}
```

If you use this code like this,

```cs
var factory = new CollectionFactory<Person>();
var persons = factory.CreateCollection<PersonsCollection>();
persons.Add(new Person { FirstNames = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
```

you get the output

```
PersonsCollection.Add: John Doe
no of items before add: 0
no of items after add: 1
```

So, if your `Add` method is not called, it must have a reason outside ouf the presented code (my omitted constructor has no influence).

As you are using `ObservableCollection` wouldn't it be a more straightforward way to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event to do *some stuff*? I see, that you put your *stuff* before the call to `base.Add(...)`, but that should solvable.

Comment: Thats weird. Can you attempt to call the add method within the CreateCollection<CT> method after creating the PersonCollection instance and see if you get the same result?

Comment: The key difference between your code and the OP is that you're calling `Add` on a collection that is known at compile-time to be a PersonsCollection, whereas the OP is calling `Add` on a collection that is only known to implement `ICollection<CT>`.

Comment: @Kikanye Yes, now the behaviour is like you described it. So maybe you can change `GetSelectedItemsAsCollection` to just return the items instead of a collection and create the explicitly typed collection and add the items at the calling site?  
Or you go with the `CollectionChanged` event.